# C# versioning with DataContract Serializaiton

Tags: datacontractserializer

I am using DataContract serialization to save my sceneario which is created in C# application.
I save several classes during the serialization. 
I want to know that if a class changes in the future and there is a missing field or an extra field in the saved file, is it possible to inform the user saying that "Field 1 is missing" or "There is an extra field in saved file".

I know that datacontract serializer can deserialize in this kind of situations but i want to know which fields are missing or extra too.

Or should i use another save mechanism in order to provide this? (Some pattern, or should i write custom serializer?)